# AWS Sign In Loop - Can't Access the Portal

Tags: loops, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-ec2, authentication

Issue: I am trying to sign in as a root user for my account from the AWS portal, but now, after I adding my password I keep getting redirected to: 
https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup?redirect_url=https%3A%2F%2Faws.amazon.com%2Fregistration-confirmation#/start, no matter what.

It was working fine till today, first time I've encountered this redirect.
Main Browser : Chrome - Version 62.0.3202.94

Based on what on similar cases found on google I tried the following and still did not manage to sort out the issue:
-Chrome: deleted all the cookies and cache data 
-Chrome: restarted the device and also the browser
-Chrome: used incognito mode 
-Firefox ([an aws member said is the most suitable browser](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=260872)): tried normal and private mode
-Firefox: deleted all the cookies and cache data
-Edge: tried normal and private mode

Someone suggested already to make use of [S3Browser](http://s3browser.com/), it does not seem as a efficient solution just to access the AWS Portal a few times a week so I am keeping it as the last resort.

If anyone experienced the same issue or has any more suggestions/ideas would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to login to IAM User ? Are you able to login to other aws account as root user ? Are you able to login to your own account on some other machine ? Are you able to login via root to aws mobile app ?

Comment: I am still baffled by this thing. I do not have an IAM user setup on this account, it's my personal one and I am the only person accessing it. I can't tell you if I can login with another aws account as a root user because I do not have one (to make a new one need another credit card which I do not have). I tried another PC, phone, tablet -> they all take me to 'Create a new AWS Account'. If I login through the app I still get the same screen 'Create a new AWS Account'.

Comment: Looking at the answer I think you will need help from AWS , tweet to @awssupport they will help you out.

Comment: Ok, will try that. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue. The following fixed it for me:

1. Change your Amazon email address on www.amazon.com - You can use the same email address by using this trick. Change myemail@gmail.com to myemail+amazon@gmail.com
2. Use the lost password recovery on the AWS login site to recover the password for the former email address (i.e. myemail@gmail.com).
3. Use the new password to login on the AWS console with the former email address (myemail@gmail.com)

Answer (score 2):

I just had the exact same problem and it was caused by my Amazon account who happens to have the same email address as my AWS account. Turns out that somehow ends up to be [one and the same account](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=85882). I finally had to change the Email for my Amazon account and reset the password on my AWS account. Now they are nicely separated.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.. found out was because of AdGuard app. Hope it will help somebody

for test you can try to login aws on iPhone

Comment: Ad blockers seem to have an effect on aws.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me in Safari 17. The solution was to open Safari settings (command + comma), go to the 'Advanced' section, and set "Use advanced tracking and fingerprinting protection" to either "in Private Browsing", or uncheck the box entirely.

Comment: Had the same problem with Safari 17.2 in Private Mode. No problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted AWS regarding the issue and they suggested to reset my password by going through https://signin.aws.amazon.com because they saw I have two accounts under the same email address. I did reset my password but this did not help and I was keep getting sent to the same screen to finish my registration.

Due to the fact that I reset my password for my AWS account, when I tried to do some Christmas shopping through the normal  https://www.amazon.co.uk it was prompting me with a message saying that I have another account active (the one from AWS I presume). I just reset my password for my https://www.amazon.co.uk account and it seems that the AWS account start working normally again.

Based on this experience if you encounter the same issue, I would recommend to try and reset the password for both AWS and the online shop https://www.amazon.com.

Comment: I facing same issue, could not resolve it by this solution.

Comment: facing the same issue as well. Resetting on both platforms did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue that also manifested itself as my amazon account not being associated with our 3rd party seller account on amazon US FBA (in addition to causing the loop on AWS).

I read the answer here and changed my password but that didn't fix it.

Ultimately, I called amazon.com customer support who transferred me to AWS support (the only way to get them is by calling general support and requesting it).  They were able to initiate a password reset request which solved both issues (seller account and AWS Login loop).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of being unable to login to the AWS COnsole because of *the AWS Sign In Loop* by **re-syncing my MFA device.**

There's a link on the 3rd phase of login, where it asks for your MFA, that says **troubleshoot MFA**. If you click it, it asks you for 2 consecutive MFA codes and then lets you in.