# AWS console sign in error 400 bad request after password and before MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, console

I cannot sign into AWS account. The AWS management console accepts password but then throws 400 error before getting to MFA. Link to Support takes me to login again, haha. I cleared cache and cookies for all of time. I tried different browsers and devices. [image]

Comment: I'm getting the same error suddenly. Were you able to make it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. Still going back and forth with AWS support via email trying to convince them that the problem is somewhere AWS side. And they want me to create a case within my account but I cannot login!

Comment: Feel free to contact support as well. If you are unable to log into your AWS account, please fill out the following form:

https://support.aws.amazon.com/#/contacts/aws-account-support

Someone from the AWS team will contact you shortly to help resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to AWS support, they said that I have two AWS accounts. That means my Amazon.com account also counts as an AWS account I guess. Both have the same email address, e.g. myemail@gmail.com. Therefore, the below StackOverflow link fixed my issue.

- I just had to modify my Amazon.com email to include +amazon so if it was myemail@gmail.com, then I needed to change it to myemail+amazon@gmail.com. Do this by logging into Amazon.com, then navigate to Your Account > Login & security
- Don't worry, you don't actually need to create an email for myemail+amazon@gmail.com
- Seems like Amazon.com removes the +amazon and continues to treat it as myemail@gmail.com as far as I've noticed so far. You are still even allowed to log into Amazon.com with myemail@gmail.com without adding the +amazon

After doing this, I was able to log into AWS account as usual. =)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57104601

Comment: You have to create a new email now because it sends OTP to it.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Open Chrome Settings
To begin, open your Chrome browser and click on the three vertical dots in the top-right corner to access the drop-down menu. From there, select "Settings."

Step 2: Reset Settings
Once you are in the Chrome Settings menu, scroll down to the bottom and click on "Advanced" to reveal additional options. Now, locate the "Reset and clean up" section and click on "Reset settings."

Step 3: Restore Settings to Their Original Defaults
In the "Reset settings" section, you will see the option to "Restore settings to their original defaults." Click on this option to initiate the reset process.

Step 4: Confirm the Reset
A pop-up window will appear, asking you to confirm the reset. Read the message carefully to understand what will be reset. If you are ready to proceed, click on the "Reset settings" button.

Step 5: Restart Chrome Browser
Once the reset process is complete, close your Chrome browser entirely. Ensure that all browser windows are closed.

Step 6: Reopen Chrome and Sign In
After closing Chrome, reopen the browser and navigate to AWS again. You may need to sign in to your AWS account. Try your previous action that resulted in the "Bad Request" error, and you should now be able to proceed without encountering the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the same unsuccessful attempts to resolve. It now appears to be fixed at least for me. Hopefully for you all as well.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted AWS support (like the OP, I had to convince them that "log in to your account to get support when you can't log in to your account" was unreasonable) and they fixed the problem for me but unfortunately provided no details on what caused it. In case anyone missed it in the comment on the question, support when you can't log in is at https://support.aws.amazon.com/#/contacts/aws-account-support .